# cakephp 2.4 isUnique validation not working

Tags: validation, cakephp-2.0

I have following code in my model .

```
'uniqueNameRule' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'required' => true,
                'allowEmpty' => false,
                'on' => 'create', // here
                'last' => false,
                'message' => 'name already exists'
            )
```

The above code validates the field name but there is an issue that when i try to insert new name it does not save it , means validation message is shown for each time .

I tried to figure out this and find that `'on' => 'create',`  is creating issue . Please help me on this thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you set the validation on the right way:

```
public $validate = array(
    'column_name' => array(
        'uniqueNameRule' => array(
            'rule' => 'isUnique',
            'required' => true,
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'on' => 'create', // here
            'last' => false,
            'message' => 'name already exists'
        )
    )
);
```

The `'on' => 'create',` line says to cakePhp that the validation must be executed only when you a creating a new register. If you are updating an existing register, then validation won't be executed at all.

Also, check if the validation error is not running on another validation block, as you set `'last' => false`, which means that validation will continue in spite of this rule failing.

Answer (score 0):

If you've issue in isUnique rule in validation. You can use **Multivalidatable** Behavior. below is the complete example how to use please visit below link.

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/dardosordi/2008/07/29/multivalidatablebehavior-using-many-validation-rulesets-per-model

Thanks